# GWT JSNI split method bug

Tags: java, string, gwt, jsni

I am developing a GWT application and I am obtaining a List containing the result of a select query. This select query has rows. Each row, has each element separated from the previous and the next by "::".

I am trying to split it using String.split, but it is taking ages to perform. I have read that currently (i am using GWT 2.5.1), the String.split method its quite bugged, sometimes almost taking x1000 times more than the JSNI method to perform; so i took that approach.

The JSNI method that i am using is the following (which i picked up from this same site):

```
public static final native String[] split(String string, String separator) /*-{
   return string.split(separator);
   }-*/;
```

But now, i am getting this error :

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$ cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

And even if I write a .toString() at the end, the error becomes the following:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

I am calling this method like this :

```
String[] temp = split(str, "::");
```

In order to get the results from the split inside temp, for later usage.

str it is a String containing an iterator.next().

Could you please tell me what could i be missing or misunderstanding?.

Thank you in advance for your time,

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript list is *not* a Java array. While GWT uses JavaScript lists to emulate Java arrays, that doesn't mean that they are the same thing.

Instead you should return `JsArrayString` from your method, and use it that way, or just use the Java version of String.split which returns a real Java array.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response, Colin Alworth.

With your answer, what i did it is the following:

```
public static final native JsArrayString split(String string, String separator) /*-{
    return string.split(separator);
    }-*/;
```

And in the java code:

```
JsArrayString temp = split(str, "::");

String agentCode = temp.get(1); (an so forth).
```

Thanks a lot for the help, it works like a charm :).