# Split the string with new line character in gwt 2.5.1?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Following code block works fine in dev mode but when I deploy to server it does not.Could not split the multi line with new line characters?
Basically, Format the multi-line string as "," separated  string tokens.

packages:

```
import com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp;
import com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.SplitResult;


 public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                String plateStr = "";
                if(event.getResults() != null){
                    String uploadStr = event.getResults();
                    //Log.warn(this.getClass().getName() + " - event.getResults():"+ uploadStr);
                    RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("\\r?\\n");
                    SplitResult sp = regExp.split(uploadStr);
                    Log.warn(this.getClass().getName() + " - sp.length():"+ sp.length() + ", SplitResult:"+ sp.toString());
                    for(int i = 0; i < sp.length() ; i++){
                         Log.warn(this.getClass().getName() + " - PlateLine["+ i+ "] - " + sp.get(i));
                         if(!sp.get(i).trim().isEmpty()){
                             RegExp regLine = RegExp.compile(",");
                             SplitResult spLine = regLine.split(sp.get(i));
                             for(int j = 0; j < spLine.length(); j++){
                                 if(spLine.get(j) != null && !spLine.get(j).trim().isEmpty()){
                                     plateStr = plateStr + "," + spLine.get(j);
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                    }
                    //plateStr = Arrays.toString(lines).replace("[","").replace("]", "");
                    if(!plateStr.trim().isEmpty()){
                        plateStr = plateStr.substring(1,plateStr.length());
                    }

                    Log.warn(this.getClass().getName() + " - PlateString:"+ plateStr);
                }
```

I tried following workaround with java script native query but it also doesn't work.

```
JsArrayString arrayString = splitString(uploadStr, "\n");

    public static final native JsArrayString splitString(String string, String separator) /*-{
return string.split(separator);
}-*/;
```

REF:
[GWT JSNI split method bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230300/gwt-jsni-split-method-bug)

Comment: Its working for me with this code. Have you tried with `String.split("\\r?\\n")`?

Comment: It did not for me, Initially I tried String split then changed to Regexp. At the end I just handled this in server side.

Comment: Good, that's the right place to solve this issue. but I am surprised why `String.split("\\r?\\n")` is not working at client side.